# Pegar valores de campos hidden e enviá-los para o back-end

Tags: react

Bom dia, tenho alguns campos do tipo hidden que são preenchidos no useEffect. Estou com dificuldade para enviá-los junto os demais valores no processo de salvamento. Segue o código:

```
function LancamentoEstagiario() {

const { id } = useParams();

const initialValue = {
    id: null,
    estagiario: null,
    mesLancamento: '',
    anoLancamento: '',
    dataInicioUnidade: '',
    dataDesligamentoUnidade: '',
    turmaEstagio: '',
    nomeAlunoEspecial: '',
    observacao: ''

}

const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValue);

const [estagiarioLoaded, setEstagiario] = useState();
const [mes, setMes] = useState();
const [ano, setAno] = useState();

const service = new LancamentoEstagiarioService();
const serviceEstagiario = new EstagiarioService();

useEffect(() => {

    if(id){
        async function loadEstagiario() {
            const response = await serviceEstagiario.obterPorId(id);
            setEstagiario(response.data);
        }
        loadEstagiario();
    }

    let dataLancamento = LocalStorageService.obterItem('data_lancamento');

    let dateConverted = new Date(dataLancamento);
    let month = dateConverted.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    let year = dateConverted.getUTCFullYear();
    console.log('Data', month + 1, year);

    setMes(month);
    setAno(year);

}, []);

function onChange(e) {
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    setValues({...values, [name]: value})
}

const cadastrar = () => {
    
    service.salvar(values)
        .then(() => {
            mensagemSucesso('Lançamento salvo com sucesso')
        }).catch(error => {
            mensagemErro(error.response.data.message)
        })
}

return(
    <Container className="mt-4">
        <Card title="Cadastrar/Editar Lançamentos de Estagiários">
        <Form>
                <input type="hidden" 
                    className="form-control" 
                    placeholder="M" 
                    id="estagiario" 
                    name="estagiario"
                    value={estagiarioLoaded}
                    onChange={onChange} />
                
                <input type="hidden" 
                    className="form-control" 
                    placeholder="M" 
                    id="mesLancamento" 
                    name="mesLancamento"
                    value={mes}
                    onChange={onChange} />

                <input type="hidden" 
                    className="form-control" 
                    placeholder="M" 
                    id="anoLancamento" 
                    name="anoLancamento"
                    value={ano}
                    onChange={onChange} />   

                <Row>
                    <Col xl={3} lg={6}>
                        <label className="col-form-label" htmlFor="dataInicioUnidade">Data de Início na Unidade:</label>
                        <input type="date" 
                            className="form-control" 
                            id="dataInicioUnidade"
                            name="dataInicioUnidade"
                            value={values.dataInicioUnidade}
                            onChange={onChange}></input>
                    </Col>
                    <Col xl={3} lg={6}>
                        <label className="col-form-label" htmlFor="dataDesligamentoUnidade">Data de Desligamento da Unidade:</label>
                        <input type="date" 
                            className="form-control" 
                            id="dataDesligamentoUnidade"
                            name="dataDesligamentoUnidade"
                            value={values.dataDesligamentoUnidade}
                            onChange={onChange}></input>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
             
                <Row>
                    <Col md={1}>
                    <button type="button" onClick={cadastrar} className="btn btn-primary"> Salvar </button>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Form>
        </Card>
    </Container>
);
}

export default LancamentoEstagiario
```

Os campos são estagiario, mesLancamento e anoLancamento. Os demais campos são capturados no onChange mas como não é feito o onChange neles, não funciona.

Preciso inserir os três valores dentro de **values**.

Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Não daria para pegar o valor acessando (lendo) o campo no momento do salvamento (no onClick do botão Salvar)?

Comment: Opa Leonardo, eu já tenho esses valores nas constantes, estagiarioLoaded, mes e ano, só que como estou passando "values" como parâmetro no método salvar, preciso atribuir esses 3 valores a seus correspondentes que estão dentro de "initialValue".

Comment: Bom, Marciel, se tens os valores, basta adiciná-los ao array desejado. Tu podes fazer isso no procedimento cadastrar, antes de chamar o `service.salvar`...

Comment: Consegui resolver, editei com a resolução no final.

Comment: Que bom! Só lembrando que tu podes responder a tua própria pergunta, em vez de colocar a solução no questionamento...

Comment: Ok, vou fazer isso então. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi adicionando os valores ao objeto antes do salvar(). Segue o código atualizado.

```
const cadastrar = () => {

    values['estagiario'] = estagiarioLoaded;
    values['mesLancamento'] = mes;
    values['anoLancamento'] = ano;
    
    service.salvar(values)
        .then(() => {
            mensagemSucesso('Lançamento salvo com sucesso')
        }).catch(error => {
            mensagemErro(error.response.data.message)
        })
}
```